# Knowing last page using Paged Data source

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using paged data source class to implement paging, i dont understand how IsLastpage works?? I didntfound much description about IsLastpage in MSDN

Depending on the page size i am retrieving the Records from the Data base.

see below:

```
    //pgsource is my Paged Data source object
      pgsource.DataSource = Bl.getEvents(true);
      pgsource.PageSize = 4;
      pgsource.AllowPaging = true;
```

Let the Bl.getEvents(true) returns 11 records

But each time i am returning 4 records per page from sql . So when i try to use IsLastpage everytime it is returning  false. I really do not understand how paging , server side paging works Paged data source. I tried using both of

- Allow Paging = true,
- Allow Server side paging = true

Screenshot of Pgsource:

[image]

Comment: Yaa...im using for that ppurpose only...But tell me why it is not returning true when it is last page...?? SEe der in screenshot...DatasourceCount=11, Pagesize i have setted to 4 it meanns, and CurrentPagindex 3 it means this is the last page right???

Comment: `IsLastPage` is implemented as follow: `return (this.CurrentPageIndex == (this.PageCount - 1));`